# What is the zero think time?

Tags: c#, performance, testing, performance-testing

I'm reading some articles about testing performance and I found

> Use a zero think time if you need to fire concurrent requests,. This
>   can help you identify bottleneck issues

What is the meaning of ***zero think time***?

Comment: Here's a site that explains [think times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184790%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It's a time you need before posting a question on SO. Lol! Actually, "the time that a user waits between performing successive actions is known as the think time."

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko Yes now is okey Lol